# Azure AD: user_interaction_required issue when authenticating a native application

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, office365, exchangewebservices

I have Exchange Online from Office 365 with a mailbox and I need to access this mailbox with my console C# application that uses Managed EWS. The requirement is that the console application should use OAuth authentication to access the Exchange Online.

I have Azure AD set up, and created an application there, received clientid and redirect uri. I have given full permissions to the application - please have a look at the screenshot below:

[image]

I'm using Active Directory Authentication Library for .NET (latest version from NuGet) to issue a token, but having a problem to get it running...

My code is:

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/rsoftgroup.onmicrosoft.com", false);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;

try
{
    var authenticationTask = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
        "outlook.office365.com", 
        "c4fa7d60-df1e-4664-a8f8-fb072d0bb287", 
        new Uri(redirectUri), 
        new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Never)
    );

    authenticationTask.Wait();
    authenticationResult = authenticationTask.Result;
    exchangeService.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken);
}
catch (AdalException)
{
    // Exception occured on the authentication process. 
}
```

I get AdalException with message: "*user_interaction_required: One of two conditions was encountered: 1. The PromptBehavior.Never flag was passed, but the constraint could not be honored, because user interaction was required. 2. An error occurred during a silent web authentication that prevented the http authentication flow from completing in a short enough time frame*"

Can somebody help me how to solve it?

I need the OAuth authentication to work without user interaction, as this will be a command line application...

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are able to use Outlook REST APIs instead of EWS, you can take a look at https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet for a Get Started code sample w/ OAuth to access an Office 365 mailbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application still needs to authenticate as some user, currently if you look at your code you don't authenticate because of PromptBehavior.Never and you don't specify any user-credentials and use the implicit auth flow eg http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/

For a standard Console apps where you are going to authenticate (eg ask for credentials when the app is run) I would use out of band call urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob (you then don't need a redirection endpoint) and set your code to prompt eg

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/Common");

var authenticationTask = ac.AcquireTokenAsync(
"https://graph.windows.net",
"5471030d-f311-4c5d-91ef-74ca885463a7",
new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"),
new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always)
).Result;

Console.WriteLine(authenticationTask.AccessToken);
```

When you run the Console app windows and the ADAL library will handle the plumbing and show the correct authentication prompts and get the Token back and you get the benefits of reduce attack surface over prompting for the credentials yourself in your code (or as parameters etc)

As Venkat comments suggests if you don't need to use EWS (eg no existing code base investment etc) then using the REST endpoints maybe a better solution if your building a daemon type application as you can take advantage of this type of auth flow eg https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/

Comment: Glen, thank you for the response. You are fantastic :-). Everything is clear to me now! Also the link provided at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/ has happened to be very helpful with a headless authentication. I will discuss it with the client regarding whether they want the ADAL prompt to appear or they prefer to go with a completely headless solution (which is less secure at the same time).